# Neural Network output all 1s

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, prediction

I am trying to create a ANN network for prediction (i.e not just classifying into 0 or 1).

My code is as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv('ANNData.csv', skiprows=0, usecols=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11)) #importing data
data.interpolate(axis=0, method='linear', inplace=True) #interpolates = fills in missing values
data=data.values #converts to array

#scaling the data
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
scaled_data = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data)
inputs=scaled_data[:,0:8]
output=scaled_data[:,8]
output = output.reshape(1095,1)

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1/(1+(np.exp(-x)))

def sigmoid_der(x):
    return (sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x)))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(inputs, output, test_size=0.2)

synaptic_weights=2*np.random.random((8,1))-1

for iteration in range(10000):
    input_layer= X_train
    outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(input_layer, synaptic_weights))
    error = outputs-y_train
    adjustments = error*sigmoid_der(outputs)
    synaptic_weights =np.dot(input_layer.T, adjustments)

print(outputs)
```

For my result, I get all ones. To put into perspective, the first 5 outputs for the y_train data is

```
[0.69083156]
 [0.07889126]
 [0.3880597 ]
 [0.3880597 ]
 [0.23240938]
```

I should mention that when I run the code for one iteration I get an output that makes sense. When the iterations are 2 or more, I get an array of all ones.
i.e.

```
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
 [1.]
```

Any suggestions? Or is the only solution to add more layers?

Comment: Is sigmoid_der the derivative of sigmoid? If so are you sure this is correct? d sigmoid/ dx = np.exp(-x)/((1+np.exp(-x)**2). Maybe it can be written as you done, but I cant see it.

Comment: Yes, it is the derivative of sigmoid. I changed it to the value you suggested and got the same result (works for 1 iteration, but all '1' for 2 or more iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using gradient descend, i think you're missing the learning rate.

try setting

```py
lr = 1-e3 # try different range from 1-e2 to 1-e5

adjustments = lr * error * sigmoid_der(outputs)
```

Comment: After adding this, I get all ones for 2 iterations and thereafter, all zeros.

Comment: @Laura is your loss function correct ? I just realized that isn't loss function for logistic regression